# Why it doesn't work that override the method '-(NString* )description' of NSDate?

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, objective-c-category

I want to use NSLog a NSDate object, and show it in the customized date formatter, for example like "yyyy-MM-dd". So i override the instance's method '-(NSString*)description' in the NSDate's Category file.But it dose not work. 
Who can tell me that how can i implement this?

In Objective-c.

```
@interface NSDate(Test)
@end

@implemetion NSDate(Test)

- (NSString *)description
{
   return @"test";
}
@end


// in the code that will actually run.
{
  NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
  NSLog(@"%@", date);

}

// but it's not print "test" at last. why?
```

I expect it run the code that i overrided in the category.

Comment: If the name of a method declared in a category is the same as a method in the original class, or a method in another category on the same class (or even a superclass), the behavior is undefined as to which method implementation is used at runtime. This is less likely to be an issue if you’re using categories with your own classes, but can cause problems when using categories to add methods to standard Cocoa or Cocoa Touch classes.

Comment: [Avoid Category Method Name Clashes](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html)

Comment: Instead of overriding a method in a category, create a subclass or create a method with other name

Comment: While a method in a category will overwrite a method in the main class, don't do that :-)  The real answer though is that NSDate is an abstract superclass, and the instance at runtime will typically be a private subclass, and that private subclass itself overrides -description so your method will not be called.

Answer (score 0):

`NSDate` already has a field called `description`

You cannot override through a category/extension. Use a subclass OR method swizzling OR use a different field name to avoid collision.